# how to have panels that load their specific contents instead of loading the whole page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I have an xhtml page that contains 3 panelGrids and 3 forms of xhtml which are loading as a whole while loading the xhtml page.I want an empty page which will have these  panels and forms and they need to load only the content specific to them after the page has loaded(EX:Like in any bank page where each panel loads only its own content)
I need to use Java,JSF,Javascript/Jquery and Ajax.
Can anyone help me solve this,please?

Comment: This is far too broad a question for SO.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for information about what kinds of questions we handle here, and about how to improve the likelihood of getting a useful answer.

Comment: I know of https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/outputPanel.xhtml which has a deferred functionality. Maybe you are allowed to use PrimeFaces for just this feature

Comment: @Kukeltje.. Thank you for the response, I basically need  an empty page loaded with empty panels which load data only after the page has completely got loaded(the empty page and empty panels need to be visible to the user and then data has to be loaded). Can you help me out without primefaces?

Comment: @Kukeltje
Can't we have multiple panels rendered in the same way , using primeFaces? I am able to do it to only one outputPanel. remaining panels are not loading as expected .I am also losing pagination. Can you please help me out?

Comment: @sai: please read the first comment below the question. Read it carefully. Something about [mcve]